# JPA container to j2se application?

Tags: java, swing, jpa

I want know if exist some container jpa to j2se ? At vaadin I use JPAContainer, is there something like that to j2se ?

Comment: JPA can be used in Java SE. What's the problem?

Comment: @JBNizet no problem ! I want know if exist some Container to work with JPA at J2SE. As I did say at Vaadin I use JPAContainer that is a Container to JPA.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by container. It must be a Vaadin specific thing. You can use the JPA API in Java SE.

Comment: all right. I already use JPA with j2se.

Comment: You can use JPA with Swing, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2531942/230513), as suggested in this possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3422516/230513).