# Set textArea1 / jTextField / jTable to display entire database row chosen by jComboBox or any choice box from a database column

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, resultset

Here trying to display the entire row from database in textArea / jTextField or jTable chosen by jComboBox or any choice box from a database column.

Can't find suitable methods like `addtext` + `ResultSet`: IDE keeps telling me that `ResultSet` can't be converted to string.

Thus like to set synchronized box and textfield, the tryouts only started together then lost synchronization.

Current situation:

```
try {

String sql="select * from employees";
pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
rs=pst.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()) {

String first =rs.getString("first");

jComboBox1.addItem(first);

String itemtext = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();

jTextField1.setText(itemtext); 
}
```

Comment: `JTextArea` has an `append` method

Comment: More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3424872/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2531942/230513).